# apt-get install python3-numpy doesn't install numpy on python3, but installed on python2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to install numpy for python3, and I used `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy` to install numpy as I use Jetson tx2.

Although the installation is successful, but numpy is installed on python2.7 not python3. How can I solve it?

Comment: How did you determine that it was installed in python 2.7 and not in 3?

Comment: There is no way `python3-numpy` will install anything for Python 2. Voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: because numpy is imported successful on python2.7, but not on python3 @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: Are you using the same python interpreter as the python3-numpy package? Can you give a link to the actual package you installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you flash your Jetson TX2 with Jetpack (version), numpy package is present for *Python2* by default and not for *Python3*.
In order to install *numpy* for *Python3* Please follow the steps given below:-
 1. Check if you have pip3 installed for *Python3*. If not install pip3.
`sudo apt install python3-pip` 
2. Then using *pip3* install *numpy*
`pip3 install numpy`
 
After installation check the location: **/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages** you will find **numpy** installed for **Python3**
 Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the python3 package manager :

```
pip3 install --user numpy
```

Comment: This is very bad advice, do not run pip using sudo.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Good observation, I corrected my answer

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because your default interpreter is Py v2.7
Check this by runnin in console:

```
python -V
```

Then you can specify Py3 installation as was commented above:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

> **Note**: Do not run this command with sudo because it will run setup.py
>   with sudo or
>
> in other words - an arbitraty upload a malicious project on PyPI this
>   is a hight risk action.

Comment: Again, bad advice to run pip with sudo.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, this is true, thanks. I corrected an answer.